# How do you add pointsInside:withEvent to xib view?

Tags: iphone, ios, xib

I'm just learning iOS programming, so sorry if this is a dumb question.

I have a view in a xib that's acting as an overlay, but I want that view to be "transparent", so that people can manipulate (tap) the views below it. I read that pointsInside:withEvent will do it (if set to return NO), but where do I put this method?

I have a viewController that owns my xib, but putting the method there doesn't do anything...

How do I add my method to a xib view? Do I have to make another view (programmatically) and add my overlay xib as a subview?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can set `userInteractionEnabled` to `NO` on the view instead. Overriding `pointInside:withEvent:` is really for modifying the "shape" of the view.

If you do want to override `pointInside:withEvent:` you will need to make a UIView subclass and do it there. However you can still add this view inside your xib. Select the view in the xib, and in the Identity Inspector pane set the class to your subclass.